# Python Dataframe error 'dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]'

Tags: python, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a different looking datetime index with the timezone. I want to extract minute and hours from it? How

My code:

```
df.index = DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 09:50:00-05:00', '2015-01-01 10:08:00-05:00',
               '2015-01-01 10:13:00-05:00', '2015-01-01 10:18:00-05:00',
               '2015-01-01 10:23:00-05:00', '2015-01-01 10:28:00-05:00',
               '2015-01-01 10:33:00-05:00', '2015-01-01 10:38:00-05:00',
               '2015-01-01 10:43:00-05:00', '2015-01-01 10:48:00-05:00',
               ...
               '2016-01-31 16:27:00-05:00', '2016-01-31 16:32:00-05:00',
               '2016-01-31 16:37:00-05:00', '2016-01-31 16:42:00-05:00',
               '2016-01-31 16:47:00-05:00', '2016-01-31 16:52:00-05:00',
               '2016-01-31 16:57:00-05:00', '2016-01-31 17:02:00-05:00',
               '2016-01-31 17:07:00-05:00', '2016-01-31 17:12:00-05:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]', name='TIMESTAMP', length=275533, freq=None)
print(df.index.date.hour)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dt` to access attributes such as `hour` or `day`.

```py
df.index.to_series().dt.hour
```